# How do I get a template to favor T* over T&?

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming

Apparently, given two templates, one that deduces T from T* and another that deduces T from T&, when used with a raw pointer the T& template is instantiated, instead of T* (MSVC13):

```
// throws if the given object's space isn't all zero
void VerifyZero(const void * ptr, size_t size);

template <typename T> void VerifyZero(const T * ptr)
{
    VerifyZero(ptr, sizeof(T));
}

template <typename T> void VerifyZero(const T & ref)
{
    VerifyZero(&ref, sizeof(T));
}
```

I really, really don't want T& to supersede T* in the following:

```
PODStruct * p = ... /* malloc or something, right now doesn't matter... */
VerifyZero(p);  // <- why in the 7 hells does this resolve to &p, sizeof(PODStruct*)???
```

Obviously, I can leave out the reference version of the template, but then that sucks when I really do want to zero-out a POD struct by reference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You get one overload taking `const PODStruct *` (`T = PODStruct`), and another overload taking `PODStruct * const &` (`T = PODStruct *`). The second overload is a better match, since `p` is a pointer to non-`const` data, and since `p` is an lvalue.

You could work around this, for example using `enable_if` with the second overload to reject pointer types. Or, as suggested in the comments, provide overloads for non-`const`-qualified pointers.

Better, IMO, would definitely be to give up on the overloads though. The added readability of a single template function more than outweighs the extra `&` you'd occasionally have to type.

Comment: He could also add another overload for `T*` (not `const T*`).

Comment: @dlf, or just an overload for `T*` and get rid of `const T*`. If the type of `*p` is `const`, then it will deduce `const` anyway. So, no need for `const` anywhere in the overloads. (And anyway, if you do `const`, you might feel obliged to do `volatile` as well)

Comment: Thanks, that's worth mentioning, added.

Answer (score 1):

If you change the pointer to non-const `template <typename T> void VerifyZero( T * ptr)` then it resolves the way you want because it is then a better match than the reference version.

Alternatively, if you create it like this: `PODStruct const*  p = new PODStruct;` then it also resolves the way you want.